# Order by date and convert to string In list

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have the following code:

```
List<EncryptionReport> result = null;
result = m_encryptionSvc.GetReportsFromRefnr(tuples);

result = result
  .OrderByDecending(e => e.Acc_date)
  .ThenBy(e => e.Acc_date.ToString("YYYY-mm-dd H:mm:ss"))
  .ToList();
```

The thing I want to Is sort by date in descending order and then parse the dates to string-format. But the parsing don't work.

How can I parse the dates to string after the sorting?

**Solution**

```
      var test = result.OrderBy(e => e.Acc_date)
                    .Select(x => 
                        new 
                        { 
                            x.Accident_nr,
                            x.Encrypted,
                            x.ExistsInStrada,
                            x.Id,
                            x.Original,
                            x.Report_id,
                            x.ReportSource,
                            x.State,
                            @Acc_date = x.Acc_date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")
                        })
                    .ToList();
```

Comment: dates do not need to be "parsed" to strings, just convert them `.ToString()`

Comment: Are you trying to sort again by this formatted string? Or are you just trying cast the date list to string list?

Comment: Please explain better what is your intent. Do you mean that you want a List of strings that represents the dates in the Acc_date field of your EncryptionReport list?

Comment: Just sort on the actual date and use select to capture the string version. result = result.OrderByDecending(e => e.Acc_date).ThenBy(e => e.Acc_date).Select(x => x.Acc.date.ToString("YYYY-mm-dd H:mm:ss")).ToList();

Comment: It's not really clear what you're trying to achieve.  The string representation of the date is something that would happen in the UI, wouldn't it?  Why are you trying to *sort* by the string representation after already sorting by the date itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want a list of strings with your `Acc_date` value formatted according to your requirements, then you need to call `Select` after the `OrderBy`

```
List<string> dates = result.OrderByDescending(e => e.Acc_date)
                           .Select(x => x.Acc_date.ToString("YYYY-mm-dd H:mm:ss"))
                           .ToList();
```

Of course you cannot assign the return of this to the same `result` (a List) variable but you need a separate `List<string>`

Comment: So I can't accomplish this on the same list?

Comment: @Bryan they are two different types. What is the purpose ? If you assign the return after the OrderBy you have your list already sorted, there is no need to run another sort on the same field

Comment: The purpopse Is to show the list data into a jquery datatable In the UI. But when I show the Acc_date, I get the wrong format in the datatable. The Datatable can't handle the datetime-type, so I must convert It to a string order to get the right result.

Comment: So I just want to cast the Acc_date field In the list o a string.

Comment: But you cannot do it here. The Acc_date field is DateTime field, you cannot store anything but a datetime there. The problem is in the UI logic the shows the list. I am not an expert in jQuery but I suppose that you should have something that takes a date and show a particular representation of that date. Nees to search about it

Comment: Okey, because I get the following format in the UI on the date: /Date(1378557000000)/. But If I change the Acc_date property in EncryptionModel from a DateTime to a String, It works. But I want to order the list by date, and I cant order by date when It is a string?

Comment: You could try to add another field to your EncryptionModel and fill it with the result of the conversion while you fill all the other fields (A task inside the code of GetReportsFromRefnr) then show that field and hide the datetime field

Comment: I solved It by make It a anonymous type. Check my updated question.

Comment: Well, of course that will work, but if your list contains lot of elements this could be a bigger problem in terms of performances or memory requirements. You have now duplicated the original list

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to get back a list of EncryptionReport after sorting. I would create another get only property in EncryptionReport object that returs a string of the date for you want.

```
public class EncryptionReport {

    //Other properties


    public string Acc_date_formatted { get { return Acc_date.ToString("YYYY-mm-dd H:mm:ss");} ]
}

List<EncryptionReport> result = null;
result = m_encryptionSvc.GetReportsFromRefnr(tuples);

result = result
  .OrderByDecending(e => e.Acc_date)
  .ToList();
```

Comment: Exactly what I have suggested in my comments below